# How can we get API to test after deploying the functions on to azure function app

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I recently deployed a sample Node.js API on to azure functions app.But,I don't know how to get an function URL to check, as we get by creating a function directly in function app. Could any one suggest please.

Comment: You could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-test-a-function) to test your azure function.

Answer (score 0):

I use Kudu to deploy a HttpTrigger js sample to function app in Azure. 
The function content is displayed normally like other functions created in portal.

And I found the Get function Url link in the function panel as usual.
[image]
If you can see the function in your function app in portal but there's no url link in your function panel, you can:

1. Try to build the link yourself.
   The link is in the format of https://{yourfunctionappname}.azurewebsites.net/api/{yourfunctionname}?code={yourfunctionkey}

You can find the functionkey in the Manage panel.
[image]
 2. Test in portal. There's a Test button in your function panel's right sidebar.

If you are unable to see the function you deployed, please check the folder structure you deployed.
One function.json file and your js file should be included in a folder named after your function.